# gradle customized targets faild to build

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task

I've got this code snippet:

```
4.times { counter->
    task "task$counter" << { println "$counter"}
}
task0.dpendsOn task2, task3
```

I expected that it will print "2 3 0"

But it fact it gives error in the last line:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'src'.
> Could not find method dpendsOn() for arguments [task ':task2', task 
':task3'] on task ':task0' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

So where did I get wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `dpendsOn`, the first “e” is missing (`d`**`e`**`pendsOn`).